# Condense a Mysql query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm looking to condense these three mySql queries into a single query

```
$qry = "SELECT DISTINCT authentication_id FROM gps_trak WHERE DATE(location_timestamp) = DATE(NOW())";
```

I'm getting the authentication using the above query, then looping through the results to get every latitude and longitude for that person today and also getting his/her name...

```
$qry ="SELECT latitude, longitude FROM gps_trak WHERE authentication_id = ".$authID." ORDER BY location_timestamp DESC LIMIT 8";

$qry = "SELECT CONCAT('forename ', 'surname') AS name FROM authentication WHERE authentication_id = ".$authID;
```

Can you write this as a *single query* so that I get

```
$resultset=array("id"=>$authID,"name"=>$name,"locs"=>$locArray);
```

*Edit: * There can be multiple latitude and longitude values for a single authkey in the gps_trak table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have MySql installed, but something like this for the query:

```
SELECT a.authentication_id, CONCAT(a.forname, a.surname) AS name, g.latitude, g.longitude, g.location_timestamp
FROM authentication a
INNER JOIN gps_trak g on a.authentication_id = g.authentication_id
WHERE DATE(g.location_timestamp) = DATE(NOW()) 
GROUP BY a.authentication_id, a.forname, a.surname, g.latitude, g.longitude, g.location_timestamp
```

You can't use limit in this sollution, you'll have to group the results in code. Maybe something like this [PHP group by](http://www.garfieldtech.com/blog/php-group-by-with-arrays) and group by authentication_id.

**EDIT**

Updated the SQL. Do something like this in PHP (for details take a look at the link above):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_unbuffered_query($qry);
$set = array();
while ($record = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
  $set[$record->authentication_id][] = $record;
}
mysql_free_result($result);
foreach ($set as $authentication_id => $records) {
  /* do something with your name and auth key*/
  foreach ($records as $record) {
    /* do something with the long and lat and you can limit it to 8 results sorting with rsort() for descending*/
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I should have specified in the question: There can be multiple latitude and longitude values for a single authkey in the gps_trak table...

Comment: @JoeAustin no it's ok I got that. It looks as though you want to limit the longs and lats to 8 for each authkey. In my solution you'd have to do that in code. I'll update my answer.